# Pygame setting volume when target is a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm in the middle of making a game and i have these explosions(expl) in a list so it isn't the same sound every time. I'm using a random.choice to "control" the output

```
expl_sound = []
for snd in ['expl.wav', 'expl1.wav', "expl2.wav"]:
    expl_sound.append(pygame.mixer.Sound(path.join(snd_folder, snd)))
```

But when i go to set the volume for that soundlist it spits this error message out

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\wep43\Desktop\Python Games\Pygames Tutorial\Pygame Shmup.py", line 311, in <module>
    expl_sound.set_volume(0.1)

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'set_volume'
```

I can't for the life of me make it not spit out this message.

I hope is makes sense what my problem is, otherwise just ask for more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`set_volume`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound.set_volume) is an instance method of the class [`pygame.mixer.Sound`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.set_volume), but `expl_sound` is a list of `pygame.mixer.Sound` objects. Hence, you have to set the volume separately for each (Sound) element in the list:

```py
for snd in expl_sound:
    snd.set_volume(0.1)
```